# How to compile C code on Linux/GCC without deprecated functions being available?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

There are old functions such as `index`, `rindex` which have now been superseded by `strchr` and `strrchr`.

Is there a way to configure the compiler or defines so these functions aren't available?

It can cause confusing warnings when:

- accidentally using `index` name outside of scope for eg - or worse, not warn and use the function in a way that's not intended.
- Older GCC versions (4.x) warn when using `-Wshadow` if you have a variable called `index`.

See:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Search-Functions.html#index-index
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/index.html

---

Notes:

- as @antti-haapala says, the global symbol `index` shouldn't be redefined since libraries may use it.
  This question is regarding the common case when a local variable is called `index`.
- At the time of writing, glibc doesn't mark these functions with the `deprecated` attribute, so warnings related to using deprecated functions have no effect.

Comment: I never dared ask this question - habitually I use a text editor for search replacing variables accidentally named with 'risky' names such as `index` etc. with something 'harmless', like `indx`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the compiler in ISO C mode. The C standard prohibits conforming programs being broken by the presence of identifiers that are not reserved words.

For example, use flags `-std=c99`.

Sample program:

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   index("abc", 'x');
}
```

Compiled with `-std=c11 -Werror` gives:

> `error: implicit declaration of function 'index' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't redefine these identifiers, as some library that you're linking against could still depend on them existing.

Comment: Right, but you may define a variable called `index` within a function, and accidentally use out-of-scope. Thats the case Im asking about.

Comment: @ideasman42 then tell the compiler to warn about that situation. `-Wshadow` should do the trick.

Comment: In newer versions of GCC (5.x+) `index` doesn't cause shadow warnings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to use `index` as a variable name without conflicting with the `index` function included in `<strings.h>`.

In this case you can override using the preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define index(s, c) deprecated_index(s, c)
#include <strings.h>

int index = 5;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", index);
    return 0;
}
```

Or override `index` with `strchr`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define index(s, c) strchr(s, c)

int main(void)
{
    int index = 5;
    char *ptr = index("text", 'x');

    printf("%s %d\n", ptr, index);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In OSX this works with GCC (on the level of issuing just a warning), but not with LLVM C compiler: `i.c:11:5: error: redefinition of 'index' as different kind of symbol`. Is there a directive for undefining built-in functions, like one would `#undef` macros? I've been through the documentation, but nothing I found seemed to work.

Comment: @user3078414 , I don't know about this type of `undef`, but have you tried  `#define index(s, c) deprecated_index(s, c)` before `<strings.h>` in LLVM? this should work as a macro replacement

Comment: That was exactly my starting point, which didn't work -in LLVM it doesn't seem to be a macro, so I started looking for ways of possibly undefining it. I can't even find where it is defined.